# Connect-MicrosoftTeams via Access Token

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

how can i generate teamstoken

```
$graphtoken = #Get MSGraph Token for following for resource  "https://graph.microsoft.com" and scopes "AppCatalog.ReadWrite.All", "Group.ReadWrite.All", "User.Read.All";
$teamstoken = #Get Teams resource token for resource id "48c35b8-9aa8-4d74-927d-1f4a14a0b239" and scope "user_impersonation";

Connect-MicrosoftTeams -AccessTokens @($graphtoken, $teamstoken) -AccountId $adminaccount
```

after generating access token, i am getting this

```
PS /home/test> $t=Connect-MicrosoftTeams -AccessTokens @($graph_tokenResponse, $teams_tokenResponse) -AccountId "66e1f802-f58b-4a65-8905-23db29d94acc"


Connect-MicrosoftTeams: Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters. One or more parameters issued cannot be used together or an insufficient
number of parameters were provided.
```

Comment: Are you trying to generate access token to call graph API?

Comment: no, I want to uses teams powershell, as per MS documentation, we need graphToken and teams token. But documentation is not very clear. I generated  the tokens , but I get the error message

Comment: Which documentation have you checked that is unclear? May be state what you need to do via PowerShell to teams and that can help understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: here is the documentation. I want to access Microsoft Teams Module using Access Token. I dont want interactive login. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/connect-microsoftteams?view=teams-ps#example-4--connect-to-microsoftteams-using-accesstokens

Comment: @user24778 - could you please confirm if you are using 2.3.2-preview?  Note says AccessTokens is new parameter is added in version 2.3.2-preview.

Comment: @user24778 - are you still facing this issue?

Comment: yea, i was facing the issue. but i scraped the requirement as it doesn't work